# How do I get a specific column name values using Axios Promise-based Http Request in Vue.js and Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

If I do this in my Vue.js script component

```
    getResumeAPIData(id){
  // declare a response interceptor
  axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    // do something with the response data
    console.log('Response was received');

    return response;
  }, error => {
    // handle the response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });


  // sent a GET request
  axios.get(`api/resume-data-returns/${id}`)
       .then((response)=>{
         this.RelationTable = response.data
         console.log(this.RelationTable);
       })
},
```

I get a response like this

```
{"id":1,"name":"userlocalvm","email":"userlocalvm@v","email_verified_at":null,"type":"user","bio":"Why","photo":"1606931001.jpeg","created_at":"2020-12-02T16:01:00.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-12-02T17:43:21.000000Z"}
```

Because of my Laravel api.php->Controller Backend code

```
      $findOrFailId = Resumes::findOrFail($forEachId);
      $foreignKeyOfResTable = $findOrFailId->user_id;
      return User::findOrFail($foreignKeyOfResTable);
```

But if I do it like this as

```
      // sent a GET request
  axios.get(`api/resume-data-returns/${id}`)
       .then((response)=>{

         this.RelationTable = response.data.created_at

         console.log(this.RelationTable);
       })
```

The added dot then the property name of the column

```js
response.data.created_at
```

I get a response

```
undefined
```

Sorry if this is a silly question as I am still quite a rookie in programming in general and the jargons that comes with it and I want learn and master javascript and php so bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the response is inside another `data` object. You might have to do something like this:

```
response.data.data.created_at
```